Cert manager stuck at certificate request generation
I'm facing issues with cert-manager and I cannot figure out what is going on !?
First, here are a few information :

It's not my server nor my installation. I'm just doing maintenance during holidays. Therefore I don't have the latest version of the YAML files used to create everything with kubectl. My version is one year old, and I'm scared to apply those files because I can rollback all the modifications.
The certmanager is working well for quite some time (few years) but recently, we closed the http port on the host, and it prevented letsencrypt from doing the renewal. This stated all the problems.
We opened the http port for let's encrypt, and .. nothing happened but errors everywhere we looked.
We tried to delete the secret linked to the certificate, but it did not changed anything

Here is the current situation :
On the cert manager webhook pod we have errors like that :
I0812 09:53:03.874206       1 logs.go:59] http: TLS handshake error from 10.1.89.64:28565: EOF
I0812 09:53:03.875766       1 logs.go:59] http: TLS handshake error from 10.1.89.64:64798: EOF
I0812 09:53:03.879793       1 logs.go:59] http: TLS handshake error from 10.1.89.64:33594: EOF
I0812 09:53:03.880875       1 logs.go:59] http: TLS handshake error from 10.1.89.64:29174: EOF
I0812 09:53:03.881673       1 logs.go:59] http: TLS handshake error from 10.1.89.64:30172: EOF

On the cert manager cainjector pod, we have errors like that :
I0812 10:29:19.348145       1 controller.go:178] cert-manager/secret/validatingwebhookconfiguration/generic-inject-reconciler "msg"="updated object" "resource_kind"="ValidatingWebhookConfiguration" "resource_name"="cert-manager-webhook" "resource_namespace"="" "resource_version"="v1"
I0812 10:56:56.450870       1 controller.go:178] cert-manager/secret/mutatingwebhookconfiguration/generic-inject-reconciler "msg"="updated object" "resource_kind"="MutatingWebhookConfiguration" "resource_name"="cert-manager-webhook" "resource_namespace"="" "resource_version"="v1"
I0812 10:56:56.451369       1 controller.go:178] cert-manager/secret/validatingwebhookconfiguration/generic-inject-reconciler "msg"="updated object" "resource_kind"="ValidatingWebhookConfiguration" "resource_name"="cert-manager-webhook" "resource_namespace"="" "resource_version"="v1"

And on the certmanager I have the following logs :
I0812 10:31:10.662087       1 trigger_controller.go:259] cert-manager/certificates-trigger "msg"="next CertificateRequest not available, skipping checking if Certificate matches the CertificateRequest" "key"="default/tls-secret-ovh"
I0812 10:31:10.662084       1 conditions.go:192] Found status change for Certificate "tls-secret-ovh" condition "Ready": "True" -> "False"; setting lastTransitionTime to 2024-08-12 10:31:10.662078262 +0000 UTC m=+3107.862847974
I0812 10:31:10.662109       1 trigger_controller.go:179] cert-manager/certificates-trigger "msg"="Backing off from issuance due to previously failed issuance(s). Issuance will next be attempted at 2024-08-13 02:09:43.000000774 +0000 UTC m=+59420.200770481" "key"="default/tls-secret-ovh"
I0812 10:31:10.710319       1 trigger_controller.go:259] cert-manager/certificates-trigger "msg"="next CertificateRequest not available, skipping checking if Certificate matches the CertificateRequest" "key"="default/tls-secret-ovh"
I0812 10:31:10.710356       1 trigger_controller.go:179] cert-manager/certificates-trigger "msg"="Backing off from issuance due to previously failed issuance(s). Issuance will next be attempted at 2024-08-13 02:09:43.00000073 +0000 UTC m=+59420.200770436" "key"="default/tls-secret-ovh"

When I describe the certificate I have the following output (I truncated useless information)
Name:         tls-secret-ovh
Kind:         Certificate
[...]
  Conditions:
    Last Transition Time:    2024-08-12T10:31:10Z
    Message:                 Issuing certificate as Secret does not exist
    Observed Generation:     17
    Reason:                  DoesNotExist
    Status:                  False
    Type:                    Ready
    Last Transition Time:    2024-08-11T18:09:43Z
    Message:                 The certificate request has failed to complete and will be retried: Failed to wait for order resource "tls-secret-ovh-mglkn-2823265456" to become ready: order is in "invalid" state: 
    Observed Generation:     16
    Reason:                  Failed
    Status:                  False
    Type:                    Issuing
  Failed Issuance Attempts:  27
  Last Failure Time:         2024-08-11T18:09:43Z
  Revision:                  20
Events:                      <none>

My guess at this point is that the cert-manager is not finding the Certificate Request and for some reason I cannot understand, it is not recreating it.
I have no idea how to force it to recreate the Certificate Request, and as I already said, I'm a little bit scared to delete objects since I cannot recreate them easily ...
Any ideas on how to proceed from here ? Do you think if we wait until 2024-08-13 02:09:43.000000774 +0000 UTC as said in the log it will recreate the certificate request ? Any idea on how to shorten this delay ?

I got and answer from a guy named pfiddes in the official cert-manager slack group. All the credit goes to him. It looks like the CertificateRequest is indeed stuck. Still don't know why, but to force a new CR, you can use cmctl : cmctl renew <cert> -n <namespace>. And it worked.
